# Join Windows 2003 R2 guest to Windows 2012 R2 domain controller

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, active-directory, windows-server-2012, domain-controller

I'm trying to join a Windows Server 2003 R2 guest to a domain with a Windows Server 2012 R2 Domain controller server. 
I get the error "The following error occured attempting to join the domain "mydomain.local" the specified network name is no longer available." DNS is ok I can do nslookup just fine.
I cannot access the SYSVOL or NETLOGON from the 2003R2 server, I get the same error "network name is no longer availalbe".
I've disabled AV / Firewall on the domain controllers and the 2003 R2 guest. 
The domain functional level is "2008 R2".
Is this setup not supported or does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
This is a new domain set up for test purposes. I successfully joined a 2008 R2 server and another 2012 R2 already.

Comment: doing an nslookup gives you the *correct* IP Address of the DC? As in, it hasn't changed since b/c of lease expiration, etc? Can you ping the guest from the DC? vice versa?

Comment: I know for a fact this works fine since we have 2 2003R3 servers in our environment (sadly). Double-check your DNS settings.

Comment: @MDMoore313 nslookup gives indeed the correct IP of the DC. And yes, I can ping successfully form 2003 R2 server to 2012 R2 and vice versa.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the domain with the 2012's firewall turned ***off***?

Comment: @NathanC DNS settings are correct, both hostnames resolve to the correct IP address.

Comment: @MDMoore313 Yes, I tried stopping the firewall service and also tried to turn the firewall off (both of the 2003 R2 and 2012 R2). No avail...

Comment: What's different?  ie. what can you think of network wise at all that is different from the 2003 box and the other 2 you already successfully joined?  Or what else is different?  Really think about it?  Or try to recreate the exact same setup for the 2003 box...put it on the same port the 2008 R2 box is on temporarily if need be.  Ping "exampleFQDN.com" and make sure the DC is replying (don't ping hostname just the domain name).

Comment: @TheCleaner These server are VMs connected to the same virtual switch and in the same port group. So "switching ports" won't help, I think. Pinging the FQDN works; the DC replies.

Comment: Ahh...hence the "guest" wording.  Is the 2003 server using a static IP or DHCP?  Try changing the 2003 server to a different workgroup name, reboot, then rejoin the domain.

Comment: @TheCleaner 2003 server has a static IP. Already tried changing the workgroup name but retried it now. This doesn't make any diffirence.

Comment: Don't know then with the info given.  Try a new 2003 guest and see if it works fine.

Comment: @TheCleaner This is my second 2003 server. The first one I installed from a template so I suspected the problem was in the template. I started with a fresh 2003 install from scratch. No difference, same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was I forgot to install SMB 1.0 on the Windows 2012 R2 server. You can do this in the "Add Roles and Features" wizard (see image below).

[image: Add Roles and Features Wizard]