# Able to join Server 2003 machines to a 2012 R2 domain?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012-r2

We're going to be upgrading our servers from Server 2003 SP1 to Server 2012 R2 soon (finally), but I wanted to doublecheck that once the Domain Controller is upgraded from 2003 SP1 OS to Server 2012 R2 OS at a 2012 R2 functional level, will the other Server 2003 SP1 machines still be able to join the domain and function properly for a while until they are upgraded as well?

I found this answer:

[Join Windows 2003 R2 guest to Windows 2012 R2 domain controller](https://serverfault.com/questions/575601/join-windows-2003-r2-guest-to-windows-2012-r2-domain-controller)

But it was asking about 2003 R2.  I'm asking about the older 2003 Vanilla with Service Pack 1.

Answer (score 4):

The forest and domain functional levels will prohibit **only** having Domain Controllers with a lesser OS. You can join 2003 Member Servers to a 2012 Domain Functional level. [See here - AD DS Functional Levels](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/understanding-active-directory-functional-levels%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)